# Server does not respond to ping - ICMP is received and nothing happens

Tags: linux, networking, routing, ping, icmp

I have a server with 2 interfaces connected with `dhcp` to two different subnets.
These 2 different subnets are connected to the same switch into 2 different interfaces.

```
# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
23: enp10s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c4:00:ad:a4:e3:38 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.201.232/24 brd 192.168.201.255 scope global enp10s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
25: enp11s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c4:00:ad:a4:e3:39 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.203.3/24 brd 192.168.203.255 scope global enp11s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::c600:adff:fea4:e339/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Routes:

```
# ip r
default via 192.168.201.1 dev enp10s0 
192.168.201.0/24 dev enp10s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.201.232 
192.168.203.0/24 dev enp11s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.203.3
```

From my laptop I'm pinging, first to `192.168.201.232`. With tcpdump on that device I see `icmp` request and response

```
# tcpdump -s 0 -i any -vvv -nn 'host 192.168.1.30 and not port 22'
tcpdump: listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
11:42:05.240967 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 62, id 53809, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    192.168.1.30 > 192.168.201.232: ICMP echo request, id 55768, seq 1, length 64
11:42:05.240994 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 42288, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    192.168.201.232 > 192.168.1.30: ICMP echo reply, id 55768, seq 1, length 64
```

When I'm pinging to `192.168.203.3` I get no response, and this is the tcpdump output

```
# tcpdump -s 0 -i any -vvv -nn 'host 192.168.1.30 and not port 22'
tcpdump: listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
11:43:57.037535 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 62, id 19363, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    192.168.1.30 > 192.168.203.3: ICMP echo request, id 55808, seq 1, length 64
11:43:58.060756 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 62, id 19364, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    192.168.1.30 > 192.168.203.3: ICMP echo request, id 55808, seq 2, length 64
```

What happens with this packet?
Why there's no `icmp` response?
I would expect the `icmp` response to go to the default gw (`192.168.201.1`) because my ip is `192.168.1.30`

There's nothing in `iptables` and statistics doesn't increase with `netstat -s`.

When I remove dhcp and interface `enp10s0` doesn't get ip, so I have one route

```
# ip r
default via 192.168.203.1 dev enp11s0 
192.168.203.0/24 dev enp11s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.203.3
```

Pinging to `192.168.203.3` from my laptop, does work.

Comment: Are you just asking why? Is an answer telling that it's normal it won't work with this standard configuration, fine? Or is there an additional non-asked question? Like... "How can I make both pings work?". I could answer the hidden question, but ONLY outside of the DHCP and configuration files context, with manual low level commands.

Comment: @A.B first I want to understand why it happens. If this is how Linux/routes works - it's fine (there's nothing I can do about it). I want to understand that my configuration is ok. And if you have additional information about how to actually make it possible, even without DHCP, I would be glad to know. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a multi-homed server, which always introduce additional routing complexity.

Your network could be more or less complex but probably looking like this:

```
                  ┏━━━━━━┓
                  ┃laptop┃
                  ┗━━━━━━┛
               192.168.1.30/24
                      ┊
                    lan1
                      ┊
               192.168.1.1/24
                 ┌─────────┐
                 │ clients │
                 │ router  │
                 └─────────┘
                   x.x.x.x
                      ┊ 
                   y.y.y.y 
                 ┌─────────┐
  192.168.201.1/24 servers 192.168.203.1/24
   ╭┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄│ router  │┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄╮
   ┆             └─────────┘             ┆
   ┆                                     ┆
 lan201                               lan203
   ┆                                     ┆
   ┆             ┏━━━━━━━━━┓             ┆
   ╰┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┃         ┃┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄╯
192.168.201.232/24  server 192.168.203.3/24
                 ┃         ┃
                 ┗━━━━━━━━━┛
```

### Why is the packet ignored?

Your problems are most likely due to the server enabling a feature for anti-spoofing protection called [Strict Reverse Path Forwarding](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3704#section-2.2) (SRPF). In a few words, an incoming packet is allowed on an interface only if the same interface would be used to route back its reply.

When both interfaces are configured and the default route is using 192.168.201.1 and you ping 192.168.201.232 from the laptop, the packets arrive at the server with the "left path" and come back from the server also with the "left path". It's possible on the server to ask the kernel what would be its routing decision.

The route to reach the laptop:

```
# ip route get from 192.168.201.232 192.168.1.30
192.168.1.30 from 192.168.201.232 via 192.168.201.1 dev enp10s0 uid 0 
    cache
```

uses *enp10s0*.

We tell the incoming packet arrives from the same interface (*enp10s0*) because we know that's what the server's router will have done:

```
# ip route get from 192.168.1.30 iif enp10s0 192.168.201.232
local 192.168.201.232 from 192.168.1.30 dev lo table local 
    cache <local> iif enp10s0
```

As it's the same side as the outgoing packet, this incoming packet is accepted (and routed to the local system).

If now you ping 192.168.203.3, packets will be routed and will arrive at the "right path", and the server's routing configuration would tell to leave the server with the "left path". This is an asymmetric route, and fails the previous SRPF check: different interfaces.

You can again ask the kernel about its decisions for this case. While the reply if it existed would be routed like this:

```
# ip route get from 192.168.203.3 192.168.1.30
192.168.1.30 from 192.168.203.3 via 192.168.201.1 dev enp10s0 uid 0 
    cache
```

using the default route and thus *enp10s0*, the incoming packet:

```
# ip route get from 192.168.1.30 iif enp11s0 192.168.203.3
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid cross-device link
```

is rejected by SRPF because the incoming interface *enp11s0* doesn't match the outgoing interface *enp10s0* it would use to reply to this IP address.

If you change the default route by disabling the "left path" and thus inheriting the default route from DHCP on the "right path", everything will shift to *enp11s0* and it will work again.

### How to make it work?

- What will probably not help much

  You can tell the system to [disable](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt?h=linux-5.4.y#n1225) the check or [relax](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt?h=linux-5.4.y#n1231) it to [Loose Reverse Path Forwarding](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3704#section-2.4). When there's a default route involved (there is) both effects are similar (ie: not much effect left at all), but it's easier in Linux to relax it (set 2) than disable it (set 0) when it's enabled elsewhere,because the [maximum value in this configuration wins](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt?h=linux-5.4.y#n1240). It was probably enabled at system boot in [`/etc/sysctl.d`](https://manpages.debian.org/procps/sysctl.conf.5#FILES) (YMMV) and could be edited there. So:

  ```
  sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.enp11s0.rp_filter=2
  ```

  And the previous query won't fail anymore:

  ```
  # ip route get from 192.168.1.30 iif enp11s0 192.168.203.3
  local 192.168.203.3 from 192.168.1.30 dev lo table local 
      cache <local> iif enp11s0
  ```

  Now two tcpdumps, one on each server's interface should see incoming packets on *enp11s0* and outgoing replies on *enp10s0*.

  If the laptop receives an answer you're done and can stop here.

  It probably won't. Because along the path, the next network element, the server's router probably *also* implements SRPF. Or it can double as firewall and might deem suspicious a packet 192.168.203.3 coming from an interface where only packets in 192.168.201.0/24 should be allowed (anti-spoofing protection, which is what SRPF is aiming at too). So the packet is likely to be dropped one step later.
- What will work: policy routing

  Whenever multi-homing is involved, [policy-based routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_routing) has to be used. It allows the route to be chosen not only with the destination address as selector for the decision, but with various other criteria, the most common being the source address. Here the source address is also needed. In Linux this is done by using additional routing tables (which as usual use the destination as selector), and having rules (which here will use the source as selector) selecting the adequate routing table. As the setup depends on the source address, this is difficult to integrate in a dynamic environment like DHCP. While it's certainly possible: daemons like *dhclient* or *NetworkManager* each have their own set of hooks to plug in scripts, you'd save time by using static IP addresses configurations and declaring those addresses reserved on the DHCP servers.

  The routes from the main table should be partially duplicated into additional tables. Should the server be also a router (eg: running LXC, Docker, VMs...) more routes should be pondered and maybe copied in the additional routing tables. Of course if those routes are dynamic (appearing when a container runs), configuring this becomes even more complex. As usual, `ip route get` helps a lot here.

  So create a routing table for each side (I'll use not-so-arbitrary values 201 and 203 for those tables) and copy only things needed and relevant to this side. Add on *each* of them a default route. There still can be only one default route in use... but one per routing table. Here adding only the default routes is enough to solve the routing problems (and actually only routing table 203 is needed). Should the layout change (eg: routing containers...), routes previously considered not needed to add should be pondered again. Also, even if not always used, there still must remain a default route in the main routing table: this will be the "default" default route. When the server is acting as client and doesn't define its source IP address when connecting, the defaut route will affect the automatic choice.

  ```
  ip route add table 201 default via 192.168.201.1
  ip route add table 203 default via 192.168.203.1
  ```

  Select them with source-based rules:

  ```
  ip rule add from 192.168.201.232 lookup 201
  ip rule add from 192.168.203.3 lookup 203
  ```

  Result:

  ```
  # ip route get from 192.168.203.3 192.168.1.30
  192.168.1.30 from 192.168.203.3 via 192.168.203.1 dev enp11s0 table 203 uid 0 
      cache
  ```

  The outgoing interface switched to *enp11s0* by using the routing table 203.

  ```
  # ip route get from 192.168.1.30 iif enp11s0 192.168.203.3
  local 192.168.203.3 from 192.168.1.30 dev lo table local 
      cache <local> iif enp11s0
  ```

  The incoming packet on the same interface thus doesn't fail SRPF anymore: same interface.

  Server's router won't get confused anymore either. Laptop's pings will work for both addresses.

  On the server, client applications able to choose a source address will indirectly alter the route chosen by their traffic (eg: `curl --interface 192.168.203.3 192.168.1.30`, `ping -I 192.168.203.3 192.168.1.30` but usually not `ping -I enp11s0 192.168.1.30` with *only* this setup for a reason described in details in this [SF Q/A answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/1127862/why-is-linux-policy-based-routing-pbr-not-working-for-ping/1128095#1128095) of mine) and it will just work.

---

### Caveat: UDP services

Configuration in last bullet above will make TCP services work correctly. But that's not enough for UDP because of the way the BSD socket API works by default.

When a listening TCP socket is bound to all addresses (INADDR_ANY: 0.0.0.0) and a client connection is accepted (using `accept(2)`), a *new* TCP socket is automatically created, with the query's (local) destination chosen as bound address. Because the new TCP socket is bound to the adequate address, when replying this address will be presented as source address to the routing stack, selecting the adequate routing rules as described above: everything works fine with TCP.

This isn't so simple with UDP when binding to INADDR_ANY. There is no new socket created automatically and *by default* there is no mechanism informing where the query was made to. So the reply won't be able to select the correct source address as happens for TCP. In OP's case when a query is made from 192.168.1.30 to 192.168.203.3, the application won't have the (local) destination 192.168.203.3 information available. It will reply without binding the source address (ie: leave it as INADDR_ANY / 0.0.0.0) to defer to the routing stack the selection of a source address. Above routing rules won't be selected and the main routing tables's default route will be used: the wrong route selects 192.168.201.232 as reply source instead of 192.168.203.3. While this reply will reach the laptop (it's fine from a routing point of view and SRPF), the laptop itself will reject it since it doesn't come from the address it chose to do the query to.

A server application in multi-homed environment being made available on multiple sides requires special support with UDP. There are two usual methods to do this:

- Bind separately to each server's address instead of INADDR_ANY

  The reply will use the socket's bound address. Since the query has reached *this* socket, that means it was made to the same destination address this socket will use as source address for replies: the one the client made the query to and the application's socket is bound to.

  For example that's how the DNS server *bind9* behaves: it will bind separately to all existing addresses on the server.

  `socat` example providing the date on port 1313: run three `socat` commands, one for each address to bind to:

  ```
  socat UDP4-LISTEN:1313,bind=127.0.0.1,fork EXEC:date &
  socat UDP4-LISTEN:1313,bind=192.168.201.232,fork EXEC:date &
  socat UDP4-LISTEN:1313,bind=192.168.203.3,fork EXEC:date &
  ```
- use the socket option [IP_PKTINFO](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/ip.7#IP_PKTINFO) (or IP_RCVDSTADDR on some *BSD) when binding to INADDR_ANY

  This requires specific application support: `connect(2)`, `read(2)` or `write(2)` cannot be used anymore on such UDP socket, instead `recvmsg(2)` and `sendmsg(2)` are required to be able to handle ancillary messages provided by the socket option and retrieve the actual (local) destination address used in the query with additional methods (described in `cmsg(3)`).

  For example [that's what will do the DNS server *unbound*](https://github.com/NLnetLabs/unbound/blob/release-1.18.0/services/listen_dnsport.c#L1138) when using the [`interface-automatic`](https://nlnetlabs.nl/documentation/unbound/unbound.conf/#interface-automatic) option.

  `socat` example (on Linux: `ip-pktinfo`, *BSD would use `ip-recvdstaddr` instead):

  ```bash
  socat -u \
      UDP4-RECVFROM:1313,ip-pktinfo,reuseport,fork \
      SYSTEM:'exec socat -u EXEC\:date UDP4-DATAGRAM\:$SOCAT_PEERADDR\:$SOCAT_PEERPORT\,bind=$SOCAT_IP_DSTADDR\:1313\,reuseport'
  ```

  1st `socat` is receive-only and forks a 2nd `socat` which is emit-only and replies with correct source address retrieved from IP_PKTINFO socket option made available from 1st `socat` with environment variables. `reuseport` (SO_REUSEPORT) is a workaround to allow two "unrelated" sockets to share the same port (on an actual application, this would not be needed because the UDP socket would be duplicated through `fork()` or `dup2(2)` or not duplicated at all and used directly).

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with systems which send all their non-link-local traffic through one interface but receive non-link-local traffic through several interfaces.

The first problem (which you run into here) is **reverse path filtering** (see `sysctl -ar '\.rp_filter'`). This feature is enabled by default and drops packets (even before they reach the firewall) which come through an interface which is not the one the response would be sent through. So you have to set this to `0` for the receiving interface.

The other problem may be firewalls along the way which see only half of the traffic and thus drop the reply packets because the connection is unknown to them. In that case you need advanced routing (policy routing), see `man ip-rule` and `man ip-route`. You have to set up an additional routing table and make the respective traffic (source address of outgoing packets) use that. With this done, the reverse path filtering problem is solved automatically.